# How to change the date pattern in jasper server 7.1

Tags: jasperserver

Currently we are evaluating Jasper Server 7.1.

We have a reporting solution on SpagoBI with having around 500 different types of jrxml format and we want to move all of those to jasper server with less modification.

The date formats which we used in Spago is MM-DD-YYYY. But it looks Jasper Server is accepting only YYYY-MM-DD date formats.

Is there any way we can make it to MM-DD-YYYY instead of YYYY-MM-DD.

We tried modifying the configuration file Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\bundlesjasperserver_config.properties with below but no luck.

Used for parsing and formatting dates by server:

```
date.format=MM/dd/yyyy
datetime.format=MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
time.format=HH:mm:ss

calendar.date.format=mm/dd/yy
calendar.datetime.format=mm/dd/yy HH:mm:ss
calendar.time.format=HH:mm:ss

repository.date.format=M/d/yyyy
repository.current.year.date.format=MMMMM d
repository.datetime.format=M/d/yyyy hh:mmaaa
repository.time.format=hh:mmaaa
```